# Single Controller for multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have url structures like this

```
/home
/about
/contact
/terms
```

I dont want to create separate controller foreach page. How to get it work using single home controller? If I make all the in single controller then it show url like

```
/home
/home/about
/home/contact
/home/terms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `global.asax` is responsible for configuring the routes, usually via `RegisterRoutes`. You can edit this to explicitly add your own patterns or individual mappings.  For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", "{action}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines in RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("About", "about", new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
routes.MapRoute("Contact", "contact", new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });
routes.MapRoute("Terms", "terms", new { controller = "Home", action = "Terms" });
```